# Most 5 set matches at a Grand Slam tournament in the Open Era?

Tags: trivia, tennis, grand-slam

What is the record for the most number of five-set matches at a Grand Slam tournament in the Open Era?
Where does the 2019 US Open (27 five-set matches) rank in the all-time list?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [data provided by Jeff Sackmann](https://github.com/JeffSackmann/tennis_atp), these are the Grand Slams with the most 5 setters since 1969:

| Year | Grand Slam | 5 set matches |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1969 | Wimbledon | 34 |
| 1983 | US Open | 34 |
| 2004 | US Open | 34 |
| 1992 | Roland Garros | 33 |
| 1994 | Wimbledon | 33 |
| 2001 | Roland Garros | 33 |
| 2010 | Wimbledon | 33 |
| 2012 | Wimbledon | 32 |
| 1976 | Roland Garros | 31 |
| 1998 | Australian Open | 31 |
| 2001 | Wimbledon | 31 |
| 2015 | Wimbledon | 31 |

2019's US Open would rank only 36th in that list.